# Setting a default flag - Many-to-Many Relationships

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

In this example, there are two `companies` and `addresses`. This is a `many-to-many` relationship. A company must have at least one address, but it can have more. Likewise, an address can be tied to more than one company (think that they're in the same building).

So there is a join table. I'd like to note what the default address will be for a given company, so I figure the table would have three columns: `company_id`, `address_id`, `is_default`.

My question is more about the `is_default` column. Knowing that there will be many rows with `0` in that column, and then `1` for the default, is this an acceptable way to handle noting which address is the default?

I figure I can put a unique constraint using the `company_id` and `is_default` column, but was wondering if anyone would see an issue with the low cardinality of the `is_default` column. The question is more in a general sense, as I know it depends on the situation, and I've only provided some details. But also to note, there will not be a massive number of rows in the table either.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The low cardinality won't be a problem. Your attribute is boolean, so it needs no more than one bit per record, so considering hardware prices, even billions of records won't make any difference.

There is an alternative which might be more practical in terms of updating and querying: Have an additional `default_address_id` column for your companies which takes the id of the default address record. If you make that `not null`, you can make sure that every company has exactly one default address without overstressing the not-too-strong constraint system of MySQL. But no matter how you decide, it won't break your neck.